# How to fix the Request failed with status code 500 when reload page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

The problem here is when every time I reload the page I'm getting this error.
which is the `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500`.

here's my code in list.tsx

```
const [state, setState] = useState([]);

    const { getRoom } = useRoom();

    const fetchData = async () => {
        return getRoom().then((res) => setState(res['data'].data));
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        (async function fetchData() {
            await fetchData();
        })();
    })
```

code for room.tsx

```
function useRoom() {

    const creds = useCredentials();

    Axios.defaults.baseURL = serverConfig[creds.server].api;

    return {
        getRoom: (params?: object) => Axios.get(`${API_URL}/room` + (params ? getQueryParams(params) : ''))
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

500 is an error code *servers* produce. That's not necessarily something you can fix on the client. You'll need to understand which request the server returns a 500 to and why. Then maybe you can change something on the client (e.g. a malformed request). Or maybe you'll need to change something on the server.

Either way, looking *only* at the client-side JS code won't help you fix this.

Comment: I try to add the setTimeout then it works. is that ok?

Comment: It's a bad idea to use a fix without knowing why it works. There are some edge cases where that's an acceptable practice, but generally speaking, you'll want to know why something does or doesn't work so that you know your fix will work. Otherwise, the "fix" may only have been a temporary workaround that may well break again tomorrow. Or it only looks like a fix on the surface. Or it introduces a new issue. Etc.